# Mac app with unity3d

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, multi-touch

I need to create a Mac app which shows 3D models and those should support the multi touch events. This will be run in a Mac computer and the touch screen will be a Mac OS X touch screen. I will be using Unity3d to create the 3D models in a scene. I want to know how I can integrate these Unity models/scenes to my Mac App.
One option is to embed Unity web player to my Mac app. But the issue is in the Web player it doesn't seem to recognize multi touch events like pinch zoom
So the other option is to integrate/embed the unity3d models to my app directly. But I've no clue how to do that. In the Unity build options I can build for Mac standalone. But it creates a .app file directly. So I don't think I can use that to integrate with my Mac app.

Any help on this is really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

why bother making a second app and integrating the unity app into the first.
Why not just make the whole thing in Unity ?

forgot to mention.. there are a couple of free Unity demo's that illustrate how to create or modify meshes procedurally (if you are trying to make anything more complex than basic primitive shapes)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm looking for the Mac app (instead of a full Unity app) because in our app, we'll have to show some html stuff.(will have to use html5). so if we go directly with Unity I'm not sure how the ui part gonna look like. In our app we'll have some html bullets on one side and on the other side of the UI we need to show the 3D models related to these bullets depending on the bullet user selects.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of 3D models are you trying to make?  Unity3D can only make primitives and really isn't designed for 3D modeling.  So if you are trying to make more than just boxes, spheres, etc. you will need another program.  [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) is free and works well with Unity. There is a plug in here that will allow you to make 3D models in Unity.  http://gamedraw.mixeddimensions.com/  I haven't tried it myself but they have a free version you could try before buying the full plugin to see if it will fit your needs. I agree with the previous reply that if you are going to use Unity you might as well make the whole app in Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dan. Actually I'm not creating the models. My client is giving me the 3D models they create in Rhino. I'm planning to import these .fbx files to unity and add the necessary functionality like rotation zoom multi touch etc in the Unity. After that I need to load it to our app dynamically.(planning to use asset bundles)